# run FileZilla package

Tags: package-management, debian, filezilla

I'm new on Debian and Linux, I installed FileZilla but I don't know how to run it.
whene I execute :

```
dpkg -l | grep -i "filezilla"
```

I get

```
ii  filezilla-common                     3.7.3-1                            all          Architecture independent files for filezilla
```

So I guess it installed.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install filezilla
```

You should then be able to run it from the Dash.

Comment: Sorry: What is Dash :p ???

Comment: The Ubuntu icon in the top left.

Comment: I'm verry sorry my question was for debian distribution not for ubuntu, it's my fault. But I guess your answer will help other. Thank you.